# Dashboard page not embedding correctly in home page

Tags: apex, dashboard, iframe, spring15

Before Spring 15 , my dashboard was getting embedded properly in salesforce user homepage. But, now i am getting a page that opens up into the dashboard page and is not a part of the home page any more ???? Is there some new change with respect to iframe.

Please advise urgently.

I have the following visualforce page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
<!--Hello {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName} {!$UserRole.Name}-->
<iframe id="myFrame" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder = "no" scrolling = "no"></iframe>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var sw = "{!$UserRole.Name}"
            var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 

            if (condition1) {
                iframe.src = "/01Z40000000MXOu?isdtp=mn";
            }

            else if (condition2") {
                iframe.src = "/01Z40000000MXQR?isdtp=mn"; 
            }

            else if (condition3) {
                iframe.src = "/01Z40000000MXOu?isdtp=mn"; 
            }

            else if (condition4) {
                iframe.src = "/01Z40000000MXOp?isdtp=mn"; 
            }

            else if (condition5) {
                iframe.src = "/01Z40000000MXOk?isdtp=mn"; 
            } 

        </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is that in a HTML Area home page component? If so you may need to use a Visualforce Area component instead. See [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm)

Comment: I am already using visualforce component but iframe is not working in salesforce after spring 15 update.

Comment: I need a way to replace iframe and open my dashboard in my homepage

Answer (score 1):

Even i was facing the same issue i got below solution:

location.href="/01ZZ00000004WuX?isdtp=vw" frameborder="0" height="450" width="350";

use location href in place of iframe.

if any one can help how i can place multiple dashboards on home page as